# Define multiple prefixes for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy

I have created CPT called "Pharmacy" which have a lot of pharmacies inside (approx 10.000)

Pharmacies offer 2 different services (**skin** & **scalp**) and some provide both services but some provide only one.

What I am trying to add is **skin** & **scalp** as taxonomies that can be assigned to each pharmacy depending what they offer.

So let's say that **pharmacy_one** offers both services then the link structure should look like this:

```
/skin/pharmacy_one
/scalp/pharmacy_one
```

Finally, these taxonomies (**skin** & **scalp**) need to be connected to custom template page-skin.php & page-scalp.php depending on the URL and display different layout.

So "pharmacy_one" needs to have 2 layout and 2 links.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: Are `aaa` and `bbb` meant to be two separate **taxonomies**, or two different **terms** in the same taxonomy?

Comment: @PatJ whatever will work to create a structure like that, but I guess 2 separate taxonomies can work :)

Comment: Updated question with more details